# How can we write Unit/Integration tests for callfire-api-client on Java?

Tags: java, callfire

Twilio has test credentials for integration test to make sure that the request is properly built. What's the alternative at Callfire? I went through the documentation but in didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately CallFire does not provide test accounts, for the unit testing I guess you can mock apache client responses in your code.